# no keynote or wallet

Tags: go-ethereum

A few times ago I bought ethereum with anycoindirect.eu.  They send it to my address but the problem now is when I want to sell it I don't find the private key anymore?  Is it lost?  I only have a transaction ID from the anycoindirect.eu.  I also see with blockchain the coin are still in my address.  Thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need your private-key - a trancaction ID is not sufficient to access your value behind this account. You should search more for the key ;-)

Comment: 'most likely'..? No. You ABSOLUTELY need your private key. Your private key IS your account.

Comment: As he was using anycoindirect.eu I left this open - did not want to research this service - perhaps there is a way through them - hence this wording ..

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start searching your email from its inception to now, and look around to see if you had copied the private key anywhere. Seems pretty straightforward from here that you don't have access to it anymore. Hope it wasn't a lot of ETH you lost, but hey you live and you learn.